# Modify a Ubuntu dkms file to Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, raid, kernel

Hi I was trying to install this kernel patch HP p410i.

https://medium.com/@terryjx/enable-it-mode-on-hp-smart-array-p410i-raid-card-on-hp-dl380-gen7-servers-4e827eeb78ca

On following this guide I was able to patch my ubuntu server.

> First step would be modifying the providedMakefile to adapt to the linux kernel source path KDIR to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which is `/lib/modules/$(KRELEASE)/build`

I just wanted help in modifying this Makefile to Debian

```
obj-m := hpsa.o
ifndef KERNELRELEASE
KRELEASE := $(shell uname -r)
else
KRELEASE := $(KERNELRELEASE)
endif
# KDIR := /usr/lib/modules/$(KRELEASE)/build
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(KRELEASE)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Please help with this file for Debian Linux kernel 5.4

Comment: With Ubuntu being a derivative of Debian, are you sure you really need to change something? Did you try it without change? What was the outcome?